# Generic method with multiple parameter

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a Generic method for the method CheckResult so that it could be used across different classes. For example, if I have a generic method then the only thing that is going to change is the classname. Here it is ClassA , another method could pass classB.

```
public bool CheckResult(Guid Id, List<ClassA> model,List<ClassA> existingEntities)
{
    var ids = existingEntities?.Select(x => x.Id).Except(model.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList();
    var check = existingEntities?.Where(o => ids.Any(c => c == o.Id && o.EffectiveTo >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();
    check?.AddRange(model);
    var dateModel = check.Select(x => new TimeInterval(x.EffectiveFrom, x.EffectiveTo)).ToList();
    return true;
}
```

**--------------This is what I was attempting to do---------------------**

```
public static bool OpTest<T>(T model, T existingEntities, Guid t) where T : class
{
    //  var existingEntities = smRepository.GetStationMapping(t, StatusEnum.ALL); //smRepository.GetStationMapping(t, StatusEnum.ALL);
    var ids = existingEntities?.Select(x => x.Id).Except(model.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList();
    var check = existingEntities?.Where(o => ids.Any(c => c == o.Id && o.EffectiveTo >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();
    check?.AddRange(model);
    var dateModel = check.Select(x => new TimeInterval(x.EffectiveFrom, x.EffectiveTo)).ToList();
    return true;
}
```

This is my first time writing generic any help is appreciated. The code is erroring out ?

Comment: Did you happen to notice WHAT error you got?

Comment: Your generic method paraneters should be List<T> rather than just T

Comment: @user1005310 - You can use the first method proposed by Tanner, due to covariance in IEnumerable<T> this works just fine and there is no need to implement your method as a generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a problem here. You're trying to access members on objects of type `T`, but `T` is an unknown type; it's not guaranteed to have the members you're trying to access that. C# doesn't like that.

I see two options here:

### The robust option

Create an interface, `IMyInterface`, with the appropriate members. Then write this:

```
public static bool OpTest(IEnumerable<IMyInterface> model, IEnumerable<IMyInterface> existingEntities, Guid t)
{
    List<SomeType> ids = existingEntities?.Select(x => x.Id).Except(model.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList();
    List<IMyInterface> check = existingEntities?.Where(o => ids.Any(c => c == o.Id && o.EffectiveTo >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();

    check?.AddRange(model);

    List<TimeInterval> dateModel = check.Select(x => new TimeInterval(x.EffectiveFrom, x.EffectiveTo)).ToList();

    return true;
}
```

### The quick and dirty option

Use `dynamic` instead. Note that if you use this, your code will break at runtime if you make any mistakes. If you don't want it to break like that, then don't use this option.

```
public static bool OpTest(IEnumerable<dynamic> model, IEnumerable<dynamic> existingEntities, Guid t)
{
    List<dynamic> ids = existingEntities?.Select(x => x.Id).Except(model.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList();
    List<dynamic> check = existingEntities?.Where(o => ids.Any(c => c == o.Id && o.EffectiveTo >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();

    check?.AddRange(model);

    List<dynamic> dateModel = check.Select(x => new TimeInterval(x.EffectiveFrom, x.EffectiveTo)).ToList();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would not even suggest the `quick and dirty` option, the first proposed method does the job just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static bool OpTest<T>(List<T> model, List<T> existingEntities, Guid t) where T : class
    {

        //  var existingEntities = smRepository.GetStationMapping(t, StatusEnum.ALL); //smRepository.GetStationMapping(t, StatusEnum.ALL);


        var ids = existingEntities?.Select(x => x.Id).Except(model.Select(x => x.Id)).ToList();

        var check = existingEntities?.Where(o => ids.Any(c => c == o.Id && o.EffectiveTo >= DateTime.Today)).ToList();


        check?.AddRange(model);


        var dateModel = check.Select(x => new TimeInterval(x.EffectiveFrom, x.EffectiveTo)).ToList();


        return true;
    }
```

keep your items as list or you cant use linq on it.

Comment: LINQ works fine with `IEnumerable<T>`. Why would you require callers to provide a List instead?

Comment: ok so adding List<T> removed the linq error but to make it work i had to refactor the class as such instead of where T : class
    I have to write where T: classA but what if T is classB. How can I write the code to accept classB as well ?

Comment: T as an object itself will accept both `classA` and `ClassB`

Comment: @user1005310 - if there are commonalities between types that the generic code needs to know about then it is best to define an interface and make that interface a constraint on the generic method and have the types implement that interface. It is even better though to adhere to loose coupling, the less your code knows about the types it uses the better and the more flexible it stays.

Comment: Class A and Class B have the same properties effectiveFrom and effectiveTo. Can you point me to an working example ?